# Fetching request for core data

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm having trouble fetching data from core data, i'm using the following tables and relationships

https://www.dropbox.com/s/e24i5ut0wr419w7/Schermafbeelding%202015-07-13%20om%2014.43.51.png?dl=0

Is it possible to fetch all shifts from a worker for a specific event.

Now i'm using this request, which gives me all of the shifts for the specific event, but i can't figure out how to fetch all the shifts of the worker for the specific event. Help would be appreciated!

```
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Shift")
fetchRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "post.event.id = %@", event.id)
```

Comment: Use "AND" condition at your format string or with `NSCompoundPredicate` ?

Comment: figured it out
NSPredicate(format: "post.event.id = %@ && ANY workers.id = %@", event.id, self.id)
Was looking for  "ANY"